# SetWindowsHookEx low-level mouse event hooking causing high CPU usage, laggy Cursor, and unresponsive application

Tags: c++, winapi

I wanted to make a simple keylogger-like program that would hook mouse events across the system and print some of them them into debug console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* mhs = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION) {
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {
            //mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, mhs->pt.x, mhs->pt.y, 0, 0);
            std::cout << "Pressed\n";
        }
        if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP) {
            std::cout << "Released\n";
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    // Set up the mouse hook
    HHOOK g_hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
    if (!g_hMouseHook) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to set up the mouse hook" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hMouseHook);
    return 0;
}
```

But I stumbled upon a problem. Upon pressing the left button on my mouse, my program loads my CPU to 100%, and my cursor starts to be wacky and laggy, like my framerate suddenly dropped to around 5 FPS.

Then, upon placing my cursor above the exit button, I press the left button again, but my app doesn't close. I somehow launch the Task Manager and conduct an attempt to mercilessly kill this process, but it won't close again. I sign out and sign in again, the app is still there making my cursor unusable.

How do I have to edit my procedure in order to get rid of this problem? I tried to return a non-zero value from my procedure, but then the click will only exist in bounds of my function, not being registered to the system.

Comment: A low-level hook is useful **only** if you plan to (conditionally) intercept input. If you just wish to observe input without the user noticing, use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) instead.

Comment: If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa

Comment: @SvenNilsson That's incorrect as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelmouseproc): *"This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook."* The costly context switch is merely another reason to avoid a low-level hook unless you need to *intercept* input.

Comment: Beyond looking at the code, I've tested your program and I don't see nor observe any problem with it. It may be due to some environmental (your PC) issue